# How do I change imported data from decimals to commas in Google Sheets?

Tags: xml, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Using the `=IMPORTHTML` function, I imported data from a website to google sheets. The page I want to import from is: https://www.tools4albion.com/refining.php?cat=ore&city=5&quantity=80&skillT4=28&skillT7=0&return=5&tax_sell=6&tax_shop=30&skillT5=17&skillT8=0&tax_order=1.5&skillT6=1, however the website uses decimals rather than commas to separate numbers (not to confuse with fractional numbers like "0.2" and so on). When viewed on Google Sheets, it creates 2 problems:

1. The numbers with triple decimals gets automatically aligned to the left rather than the usual right.

[image: Screenshot of Google Sheets with numbers misaligned to the left]

2. It leaves some very important data to indent, which completely changes it's value (the value is supposed to be 545760 but google sheets displays it as 545.##)

   [image]

   [image]
3. No calculations, functions or arithmetic can be performed on triple-decimal data. Even those with decimal are treated as fractional numbers rather than integers.

   [image]

   [image]

For those of you who want to try it, I used the formula:

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://www.tools4albion.com/refining.php?cat=ore&city=5&quantity=80&skillT4=28&skillT7=0&return=5&tax_sell=6&tax_shop=30&skillT5=17&skillT8=0&tax_order=1.5&skillT6=1","table",5)
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this issue? If there is no such solution that exist on Google Sheets. I have no problem doing this with Microsoft Excel. Answers from either software is fine with me.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXMATCH(""&IMPORTHTML(
 "https://www.tools4albion.com/refining.php?cat=ore&city=5&quantity=80&skillT4=28&skillT7=0&return=5&tax_sell=6&tax_shop=30&skillT5=17&skillT8=0&tax_order=1.5&skillT6=1",
 "table", 5), "\d+\.\d+\.\d+$|\d+\.\d+$"), SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTHTML(
 "https://www.tools4albion.com/refining.php?cat=ore&city=5&quantity=80&skillT4=28&skillT7=0&return=5&tax_sell=6&tax_shop=30&skillT5=17&skillT8=0&tax_order=1.5&skillT6=1",
 "table", 5), ".", )*1, IMPORTHTML(
 "https://www.tools4albion.com/refining.php?cat=ore&city=5&quantity=80&skillT4=28&skillT7=0&return=5&tax_sell=6&tax_shop=30&skillT5=17&skillT8=0&tax_order=1.5&skillT6=1",
 "table", 5)))
```

Comment: Hi, this solve most of the problems. However, problem number 1 (in my original post) still exist. I can't mark this answer as the correct answer yet, is there a way to change the formula to solve problem #1?